# Bootstrap progressbar -- Get the text centered no matter the progress

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see on the screenshot below, the text is centered in the middle of the progressbars' current progress.
[image]
**Is there a way** to make this text '**overlap**' the progress, seperating it, and **being centered of the entire width**, and the progress would show behind?

This would then be something like:
[image]

The code used for 4 progress bars are found [here. (regular docs)](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress)

I do not have my own code posted, because I don't have any code to recreate what I want.

Comment: Put a div inside the progress div then set: position:absolute;text-align:center;line-height:=height-progressbar

Comment: Answers go down there, @kollein.

Comment: As you can see, any markup inside `.progress-bar` is replaced by the script. http://fiddle.jshell.net/zyruaqeu/1/ You'd need to modify the Bootstrap core, I think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make it possible by wrapping the progress bar title in another `div` as shown in below snippet:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px; /* line-height should be equal to bar height */
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-title">60%</div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-title">Progress Bar Title Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks beautiful, let me have a go at it and I'll comment with updates ;)

Comment: The 'top;' could be removed, as it works without it, and kind-of gives an error, expecting a number after it. However, works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Paramone you are welcome. Actually I wants to write `top: 0` but mistakenly made an incomplete post. Anyway it will work in both cases :)

Comment: Still works on Bootstrap4.4, css is now `line-height: 1rem;` for defult progress bar